# Recursive Table Views in Storyboards iOS 4.2

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, storyboard

I want to set up a recursive Table View in Storyboards.  By recursive, I mean you click on an item in the TableView and it loads a new instance of the Table View, just with the new data displayed.  This way, I can reuse the Table View Cells and logic contained in the Table View Controller. My data is in arrays of arrays of arrays...

The only work around I can find is to set u a navigation controller that has my Table View Controller as the root view controller and then have that Push another instance of my Table View Controller.  This second Table View Controller then Pushes the original Table View Controller and I have my recursive Table View Controllers.  I'm just trying to eliminate the duplication of the Table View Controller (even though it is only once).

Thanks

**Picture For Reference of What I Have**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you expand the Document Outline view on the left side of the Storyboard editor, you can control-drag from the table cell to the same view controller the table cell is in.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but the only thing it's can do is defining the cell as the delegate... So not much use if you want to have a recurisve view in your storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do something like this as well. I hooked the Cell Prototype up to the segue by zooming out to a higher level like you have in your screenshot, then right-clicking the cell and dragging down into the TableView. That gave me the usual segue options.

Comment: This is not how it's done because the question is how to connect a UITableViewController to itself and not a UITableViewCell to a UITableViewController...

Comment: There is no segue option for UITableViewController to anywhere else, at least not in the way he's wanting. The segue starts at a UITableViewCell and leads to some other UIViewController sub-class... This makes sense because it's a Cell that's being interacted with to move to the next view, not the TableView itself. In this case, you want to hook it up to another instance of the containing UITableViewController (possibly with different parameters, like going deeper in a tree structure).

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to forget about the segue on the storyboard pointing to itself. Just use didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method, manipulate your data in it, create your viewcontroller and push in the table view stack. Init in you next view with prepareForSegue.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //initiate you new array
    self.arrayForNewView = someArray;
    //Now it's important that you give your table view controller in the identity inspector a Storyboard ID. In this case "MyGenericTableViewController"
    UIViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyGenericTableViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //set data source next generic table view controller
    MyGenericTableViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.dataSource = self.arrayForNewView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you can't design your storyboard to use the same UITableViewController subclass, to be used recursively.  Just design the storyboard as such, then use prepareForSegue: method to pass the selection to the next instance of the controller.

Have you tried this without success?  What problems did you encounter?

Comment: The problem is I can't figure out how to connect the ViewController to itself in Storyboards, so I'm forced to create a second, duplicate ViewController.  The first one segues to the second, and the second segues to the first, getting me my recursion.  I'd like to avoid that second, duplicate copy (just makes more code in the Storyboard to keep track). I'll put a screen shot up to show what  I've got.  Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't connect the view controller to itself.  You'd create two view controllers which use the same subclass (your view controller).  So in the identity inspector, you'd change Class to 'YourViewController' name for all the view controllers you want to recurse.

Comment: That's what I did.  But now I have to keep the two instances of the view controller in sync (if I add an IBOutlet, I have to be sure to do it to both).  Not the end of the world, just a possible place for error later.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar situation where I was asking the user a bunch of
questions one after another.  What I did was put a 'Next' button
with its own action in the VC, then in that action method instantiate
the same VC to the next question with the next questions details.
Of course the first question is the VC itself, then each successive
question is another instantiation of the VC.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
QuestionTableViewController *nextVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"QuestionTableViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:NO];
```

Note the NO for animated.  It seems that the unwind will give you
problems if you say YES.  Haven't figured that one out yet.

I had to do this because at the end of questions I wanted to do an
unwindSegue and I didnt want to use more than 1 button on the screen
to go back at the end.